# Problem with the upgrade of quarkus app from the 2.6.3.Final (last working version) to the 2.8.2.Final version - maybe external module beans' lookup

Tags: java, upgrade, quarkus, jandex

Situation: I have a Quarkus application which uses another quarkus application's beans (added as a maven dependency) for RESTEASY calls to some HTTP rest service. After updating Quarkus 2.6.3.Final to 2.8.2.Final, I am getting following errors when starting the app in dev mode by running `mvn clean compile quarkus:dev`

```
2022-04-29 15:42:04,755 INFO  [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Attempting to start live reload endpoint to recover from previous Quarkus startup failure
2022-04-29 15:42:04,763 ERROR [io.qua.run.boo.StartupActionImpl] (Quarkus Main Thread) Error running Quarkus: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:66)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:120)
        at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003190: Could not find constructor for class: io.quarkus.rest.client.reactive.runtime.RestClientReactiveCDIWrapperBase
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata.ResourceBuilder.getConstructor(ResourceBuilder.java:852)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.registered(POJOResourceFactory.java:59)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:245)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:227)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:208)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:192)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:175)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addPerRequestResource(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:87)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.registerResources(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:518)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.registration(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:475)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.startInternal(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:164)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.start(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:121)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.ResteasyStandaloneRecorder.staticInit(ResteasyStandaloneRecorder.java:43)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ResteasyStandaloneBuildStep$staticInit345281060.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ResteasyStandaloneBuildStep$staticInit345281060.deploy(Unknown Source)
        ... 16 more
```

This seamed to be somehow connected to that external quarkus "module/library" already mentioned above as after removing it from the code and pom.xml of the main app started just fine.

The external module is linked to the main application through.

```
# from pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.service.xyzclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyzrestclient</artifactId>
    <version>${xyzrestclient.version}</version>
</dependency>


# baens lookup from the application.properties

#activation of CDI bean lookup for xyzrestclient
quarkus.index-dependency.acme.group-id=org.service.xyzclient
quarkus.index-dependency.acme.artifact-id=xyzrestclient
```

Well, my assumption was that for some reason the lookup for the externally defined beans stopped working, so the app was not able to start.

Did anybody hit the same issue ?

By the way 2.6.3.Final was last version were it worked. I have also tried to generate jandex index in the external module yet it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I figured out that this was a problem with some pom.xml dependencies due to migrating to the higher version of Quarkus. So, I had to change / migrate following dependencies.

Old dependencies:

- io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-mutiny
- io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive:resteasy-reactive

New dependencies:

- io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson
- io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive

So, the problem was not caused by some issues in the beans lookup.